# Ivy Resolver Namespaces and the Resolve task

Tags: ivy

I am working with two ivy repositories that have inconsistent naming,  I am looking at using namespaces to help with the mappings, but do namespaces affect operations besides "install" such as "resolve"?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the [namespace doco](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.1.0/tutorial/build-repository/advanced.html) in the manual.... I think this approach would be overly complex.

I suggest creating two repository declarations as follows, with the appropriate file system pattern:

```
<ivysettings>
  <settings defaultResolver="central"/>
  <resolvers>
    <!-- Default resolver used to resolve 3rd party software from Maven Central -->
    <ibiblio name="central" m2compatible="true"/>

    <!-- Team1's repository. ivy and artifact patterns can be customized -->
    <filesystem name="team1-repo">
      <ivy pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/repo/1/[organisation]/[module]/ivys/ivy-[revision].xml"/>
      <artifact pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/repo/1/[organisation]/[module]/[type]s/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
    </filesystem>

    <!-- Team2's repository. ivy and artifact patterns can be customized -->
    <filesystem name="team2-repo">
      <ivy pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/repo/2/[organisation]/[module]/ivys/ivy-[revision].xml"/>
      <artifact pattern="${ivy.settings.dir}/repo/2/[organisation]/[module]/[type]s/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
    </filesystem>
  </resolvers>

  <!-- This optional section tells which resolver to use. 
       Alternative setup a chain resolver above -->
  <modules>
    <module organisation="team1" name=".*" resolver="team1-repo" />
    <module organisation="team2" name=".*" resolver="team2-repo" />
  </modules>
</ivysettings>
```

Notes:

- Obviously this example could be updated to use url resolvers if the ivy repository is located remotely.